# Prove the following function is injective/surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following problem using notation and terms I do not fully understand.

Let f: X $\to$ Y be a function. Prove that:

If there exists a function g: Y$\to$X such that g$\circ$f = 1$_X$, then f: X$\to$Y is injective

If there exists a function h: Y$\to$X such that f$\circ$h = 1$_Y$, then f: X$\to$Y is surjective

My problem starts with understanding what injective and surjective. These terms haven't been used in class, so I am not sure what the question is ultimately asking.

Secondly, I do not know what 1$_Y$ is equivalent to, or what it is in reference to.

Lastly, the prof gave us this bit of information that I do not fully understand:

f: X$\to$Y. If there exists g:Y$\to$X and h:Y$\to$X $\in$ g$\circ$f  then  f:X$\to$Y is bijective.

What makes this true? What does it mean for something to be bijective? I would assume that it means both subjective and surjective, but I cannot be certain.

Comment: Look at the links in the comment here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553186/left-inverse-iff-injective-right-inverse-iff-surjective

Comment: This sounds like a case for asking your instructor, who will know exactly what you need for this course, not for getting random advice from the internet.

Comment: The functions $g$ and $h$ are respectively [left and right inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) for $f$. The functions $1_X$ and $1_Y$, usually denoted by $\operatorname{id}_X$ and $\operatorname{id}_Y$, are [identity functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. A function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be injective (or one-to-one) if for all $x,x'\in X$, $f(x)=f(x')$ implies $x=x'$...

Comment: ... It is said to be surjective if for every $y\in Y$ there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. A function is said to be bijective if it is both injective and surjective. It is a theorem that if $f$ has a left and a right inverse then $f$ is bijective (and indeed it is a consequence of the two propositions you want to show).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are colloquial terms often used for "injective" and "surjective". They are "one-to-one" and "onto" respectively. "Bijective" just means "both injective and surjective", or "one-to-one and onto".

To understand them, we need to back up and look again at the definition of a function. Recall that a function actually consists of 3 objects $(f, A, B)$. $A$ is a set, called the *domain* of the function, $B$ is a set, called the *codomain* of the function, and $f$ itself is a rule that matches each $a \in A$ with exactly one $b$ in $B$. If $a$ is matched to $b$, then we use the symbolry $f(a)$ to mean $b$.

Some important things to note about that definition:

- $f$ is required to match *every* element of $A$ with something in $B$.
- $f$ is NOT required to match every element of $B$ with anything in $A$.
- for each $a \in A$, there is only one $b \in B$ that is matched to it.
- for each $b \in B$, $b$ may be the match of any number (including zero) of different $a\in A$.

So for example I can define $f : \{1,2,3\} \to \{4, 5, 6, 7\}$ by $f(1)=4, f(2) = 6, f(3) = 6$. This is a function. $1, 2, 3$ are each carried to only one element of the codomain. But $f(2) = f(3)$, while $4$ and $7$ are not the image of anything under $f$. The codomain of $f$ is actually bigger than is needed. This is allowed in our definition of function, because there are many times when such functions are useful. For example, $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, f(x) = x^2$ would not count as a function if we did not allow these.

The terms *Injective*, *surjective* and *bijective* are introduced for those times when we don't want to allow this to happen. They are further conditions on functions that forbid it:

- A function $f : A \to B$ is *injective* if for every $x, y \in A$, if $x \ne y$, then $f(x) \ne f(y)$. An equivalent way of stating this is: for every $x, y \in A$, if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x = y$. So no element of $A$ is matched to more than one element of $B$ (because $f$ is a function) and no element of $B$ is matched to more than one element of $A$ (because $f$ is injective). So this condition is also called "one-to-one".
- A function $f : A \to B$ is *surjective* if for every $b \in B$, there is some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Surjective just means the codomain $B$ isn't any bigger than it needs to be. There is nothing in it that is missed by $f$. Thus $f$ is said to be "onto $B$".
- A function is bijective if it is both one-to-one and onto.

On any set $A$, $1_A$ denotes the identity function: $1_A : A \to A : a \mapsto a$. That is, for each $a \in A, 1_A(a) = a$.

---

Now, you are given a function $f:X\to Y$.
The first question is:

- Show that if there exists $g : Y \to X$ such that $g\circ f = 1_X$, then $f$ is injective.

Translated: you are given that there is a $g : Y \to X$ such that for all $x \in X, g(f(x)) = x$. From this, prove that for all $x \in X, r \in X$, if $f(x) = f(r)$, then $x = r$.

The second question is:

- Show that if there exists $h : Y \to X$ such that $f \circ h = 1_Y$, then $f$ is surjective.

Translated: you are givent that there is an $h : Y \to X$ such that for all $y \in Y, f(h(y)) = y$. From this, prove that for all $y \in Y$, there is an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.

---

Finally, your last statement is incomplete. It should be: If there exists $g : Y \to X, h : Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f = 1_X$ and $f \circ h = 1_Y$, then $f$ is bijective.

This follows automatically from the previous statements.

If you think about each of these statements, you will see that $g$ "undoes" $f$, so it can be used to prove that $x = r$. And $h(y)$ provides you with the value $x$ you need for $f(x) = y$.

(And once you get those, see if you can go one step farther and prove that if $f$ is bijective, then $g = h$.)